Vuforia camera displays inverted colors
Im having the a problem with Vuforia camera showing inverted colors, it is an Unity app and it only happens (so far) in a single phone (Android). I see that the issue has been reported before, but no solution was given. Is there any way to solve this?
Googled, checked the old Vuforia forums, but I see no solution.

This must be a device specific problem. Check that you are using the latest Vuforia Engine version. If the problem persists I would file a bug report here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/

I know, but the same device is working perfectly with two other apps using an even older version of Vuforia (I updated to 10.17 and that didnt solves the problem).

the last version is 10.22. In any case if you already updated Engine and in case Unity and went through the obvious troubleshooting (see here https://developer.vuforia.com/library/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-your-app). Then you should really file a bug report

I tried 10.22. After a quick test, I couldnt make work my image targets again. I will give ita a second chance later.
